How to set ShutterSpeed of android Ricoh Theta X using Java?
I am using THETA Plug-in to set shutter speed for thetaX camera 360.
However I didn't notice any changes on the camera.
This is code i tried:
import theta360.hardware.Camera;

String value = "1/30"; // value of 1/16000 to 60 can be set.
Camera thetaCamera = ThetaCapturer.getThetaCamera(); // instance of Camera
Camera.Parameters parameters = thetaCamera.getParameters();
parameters.set(Camera.Parameters.RIC_EXPOSURE_MODE, Camera.Parameters.RIC_MANUAL_EXPOSURE);
parameters.set(Camera.Parameters.RIC_MANUAL_EXPOSURE_TIME_FRONT, value);
parameters.set(Camera.Parameters.RIC_MANUAL_EXPOSURE_TIME_REAR, value);
thetaCamera.setParameters(parameters);

Is there any solution for this?
Plugin version: 3.3.0, link: plugin
Below are the documents I followed:
Theta-api-specs: shutter-speed
Theta-plugin-webrtc-sample: CameraOption
